# Magento 2 Order Confirmation Emails Not Sending

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

Currently having an issue with order confirmation emails not sending.

I have looked at various forums / solutions and these haven't worked.

My existing setup is using the MagePlaza SMTP to send email using Mandrill, this is working through their test function and also the Forgotten Password and Create account emails are being sent but not the Order Confirmation emails.

I am using IWD One Step checkout but have also disabled this to try with Magento default checkout and it doesn't work using either.

Asyncronous sending is set to disabled but I have also tried with it enabled. Both times no order emails are sent.

As I'm using Mandrill I have checked their API logs and the API request isn't being sent.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any other module related to order emails ?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the "From" address is wrong.

Goto **Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses** and check if "*Sales Representative*" Email address is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is known bug in Magento 2.2.4/2.2.5/2.2.6 and you might be afected by it:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952.

TLDR: There is no from data set on email transaction and messeges aren't sending at all.

Try thisfix:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952